# I am getting flask error 404 but my code is correct

Tags: python, flask

I am a newbie to flask and i am running a simple code-

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask("__name__")

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<h1>Home page!</h1>"

app.route("/about")
def ab():
    return "about page"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

i am getting error code 404.

EDIT-
It automatically hot fixed up

Comment: 404 Response code occurs when the requested resource is not found.  What resource (url) are you requesting from the server?

Comment: What this means.? I am using localhost:5000

Comment: Your app only defines a route `/` and `/about`, so you'll have to try `localhost:5000/` or `localhost:5000/about`.  As pointed out in Matt's answer, your app route for about is declared incorrectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.route("/about")` should be `@app.route("/about")`.  Your client probably can't find the `/about` resource because it is defined incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Matt's answer, I would like to add that you can access your website by going to 127.0.0.1:5000 in your browser.